# Pass vault password to vagrants ansible_local provisioner

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrant-provision, ansible-vault

I'm using the `ansible_local` provisioner for my vagrant box. Some of my variables should be stored in a vault file.

While the ansible provisioner provides `ask_vault_pass` as configuration option (https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html#ask_vault_pass), the `ansible_local` does not.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `vault_password_file` option.

### 1. echo to password file

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = '...'

  config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "echo 'password' > /tmp/vault_pass"

  config.vm.define :controller do |machine|
    ...

    machine.vm.provision 'ansible_local' do |ansible|
      ...
      ansible.vault_password_file = "/tmp/vault_pass"
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

### 2. use `.synced_folder`

Create `vault_pass` file, like following.

```
mkdir provision
cd provision
echo password > vault_pass
```

and `Vagrantfile` is following.

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = '...'

  config.vm.synced_folder "./provision", "/provision", id: "ansible", owner: "vagrant", group: "vagrant", mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=664"]

  config.vm.define :controller do |machine|
    ...

    machine.vm.provision 'ansible_local' do |ansible|
      ...
      ansible.vault_password_file = "/provision/vault_pass"
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest another approach to sujoyu's answer by asking the user to input the vault password when provisioning. Also inspired by this [answer](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/2662#issuecomment-328838768).

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "..."

  # Password Input Function
  class Password
    def to_s
      begin
      system 'stty -echo'
      print "Ansible Vault Password: "
      pass = URI.escape(STDIN.gets.chomp)
      ensure
      system 'stty echo'
      end
      print "\n"
      pass
    end
  end

  # Ask for vault password
  config.vm.provision "shell", env: {"VAULT_PASS" => Password.new}, inline: <<-SHELL
    echo "$VAULT_PASS" > /tmp/vault_pass
  SHELL

  # Run ansible provision
  config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|

      ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
      ansible.vault_password_file = "/tmp/vault_pass"

  end

  # Delete temp vault password file
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    rm /tmp/vault_pass
  SHELL

end
```

Answer (score 0):

for vagrant version 2.2.9 using `ansible.vault_password_file` was resulting in

```
vault_password_file` does not exist on the host:
```

use [ask_vault_pass](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible#ask_vault_pass) option

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = '...'

  config.vm.define :controller do |machine|
    ...

    machine.vm.provision 'ansible_local' do |ansible|
      ...
      ansible.ask_vault_pass = true
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is not working with vagrant 2.2.19 :`ansible local provisioner: The following settings shouldn't exist: ask_vault_pass`